# why is ADT -03:00 in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I changed the time zone to Atlantic, so when i save a record with the time '2012-04-19  02:00 pm', it returns 'Thu, 19 Apr 2012 14:00:00 ADT -03:00' when i retrieve it. Is the 'ADT -03:00' is just wrong because ADT is never suppose to be -03:00? why is that?

Comment: [Atlantic Daylight Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/adt.html) is 3 hours behind UTC, so nothing is wrong.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is here. ADT is UTC-3.

Comment: i am at new york, is that suppose to be ADT?

Comment: No, New York is in the Eastern time zone, currently under Daylight Savings Time.  Standard time is five hours behind UTC, daylight savings time is four hours behind.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your environment.rb file in config and put in:

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

That should eliminate your problem. The timezone you have set ADT is for Nova Scotia etc.

Comment: i am trying to dynamically catching the time zone from javascript to rails, any tips and tricks?